# Prove that $\rho$ is irreducible iff $Mρ(x)=ρ(x)M$ implies $M = \lambda E$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

> Let $\rho \colon G \rightarrow \operatorname{GL}(n; \mathbb{C})$ be a representation of a finite group $G$. Prove that $\rho$ is irreducible exactly when each matrix $M \in \operatorname{Mat}(n;\mathbb{C})$ with $Mρ(x)=ρ(x)M$, for each $x \in G$, is of the shape $λE$ for a scalar $λ \in \mathbb{C}$.

Can anyone give me some help?

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on?

Comment: I don’t see why if ρ is irreductible M has to be equal to λE, because I can’t suppose that G is abelian and so that degρ=1, right? @anomaly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $M$.  Then $M-\lambda E$ has non-trivial kernel $N\subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$.

Then $N$ will be a nontrivial subrepresentation of $\rho$.  As $\rho$ irreducible, $N=\mathbb{C}^n$.  That is $M-\lambda E=0$, so $M=\lambda E$